# Node.js stream-adventure duplexer_redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

This is a question from substack's stream-adventure question set. Link to question and solution is here:

https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure/tree/master/problems/duplexer_redux

I don't understand how the "write" method could work correctly in the solution:

```
function write (row) {
    counts[row.country] = (counts[row.country] || 0) + 1;
}
```

Specifically, is there any guarantee that "row" will be full record like below? Is it posssible that "row" could be partial record?

{"short":"OH","name":"Ohio","country":"US"}

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by "partial record"?  Do you mean you'll be sent a row without the country property?

Comment: I think the writable stream will always write a line that contains country property. However, when through-stream's write method is called with data chunk in "row", a full record line might get split? For example, #1 "row"={"short":"OH","name", #2 "row"=":"Ohio","country":"US"}

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the code, it appears that `duplexer` is setting `stream.write` to call the `write` function on the input `writer` (which in this example is the `through` instance).  So when `duplexer.write` is called it's calling it's `writer.write`:
https://github.com/Raynos/duplexer/blob/6d6f4b5b85964f7037917a9a3b70659c6e152f21/index.js#L44-L48

```
function proxyWriter(methodName) {
    stream[methodName] = method

    function method() {
        return writer[methodName].apply(writer, arguments)
    }
}
```

Within `through` it uses the input `write` as the `write` variable if it's supplied:
https://github.com/dominictarr/through/blob/6f814a601b37db1f44113e56a1eaa0c32a33b0a2/index.js#L14

```
write = write || function (data) { this.queue(data) }
```

And when it's own `stream.write` function is called (`stream` is returned for the `through`), it calls `write`'s instead:
https://github.com/dominictarr/through/blob/6f814a601b37db1f44113e56a1eaa0c32a33b0a2/index.js#L25-L28

```
stream.write = function (data) {
  write.call(this, data)
  return !stream.paused
}
```

So all of that to say, when `write` is called on the `duplexer`, it looks as though it calls your defined `write` function passing the arguments it received.  So you should receive the entire argument each time.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Cool, thanks for digging into this. So looks like it was effectively a direct call to my "defined write function", right? (e.g. there is no buffering/truncate/concat mechanism in between). If that's the case, then entire argument would be received as is.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The only way I would see anything different is if you don't pass in a `write` to the `through` call, in which case it would use `function (data) { this.queue(data) }` as the `write` function.  But even then they don't break the data written up in the `drain()` call.